# Using MKMapView with a custom MKOverlay. Can the local attractions that come with Apple Maps by default appear above the overlay layer?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have an `MKMapView` with an `MKOverlay` on top, I'm wondering if its possible to have road names, place names, places of interest and everything like that, that comes by default with Apple Maps, can be displayed above my `MKMapView` so I don't have to add all this information manually as annotations. I know this is possible with the Google Maps API on Android so wasn't sure if I could do this with Apple Maps.

I've added an image that shows iOS versus Android to show what I am envisioning:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found a solution to this issue. If you're using the `addOverlay:` method in `MKMapView`, you can use:
`[self.myMapView addOverlay:customOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];`

`MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads` means place labels including shields and point of interest icons are shown above your overlay.
`MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels` means your overlay will appear on top of everything (which i believe is the default based on my experiences).